# Parsing data from blade form to controller using request

Tags: laravel, parsing, controller

I want to parsing my label name="predictDataTemp" in form into my controller, I already set the value form my label, but when I want to request the data still null

content.blade.php

```
<div class="form-group" align="center">
      <label for="exampleResult" name="result">Result</label>
      <label for="examplePredict" id="predictData" class="form-control">
        <input type="hidden" name="predictDataTemp">
      </label>
    </div>
```

controller

```
  public function result(Request $request){
  $this->validate($request,[
    'mCalories'=>'required',
    'mCholesterol'=>'required',
    'mFat'=>'required',
    'mProtein'=>'required',
    'mSugars'=>'required'
  ]);
  $item= array();
  array_push($item,array('Calories'=>$request->mCalories,'Cholesterol'=>$request->mCholesterol,'Fat'=>$request->mFat,'Protein'=>$request->mProtein,'Sugars'=>$request->mSugars,'Predict'=>$request->predictDataTemp));
  return json_encode($item);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input has no value.

If you want to give it a value with jQuery (looking at your previous comments)

Give the input an id

```
<input type="hidden" name="predictDataTemp" id="predictDataTemp">
```

Then assign it in jQuery

```
$('#predictDataTemp').val('pass value here');
```

Answer (score 0):

`label` don't have name attribute, it has only two attribute `for` and `form` so you can pass value in hidden input tag, [Read this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label)

Instead

```
<label type="text" for="examplePredict" id="predictData" name="predictDataTemp" class="form-control"></label>
```

Use this

```
<label type="text" for="examplePredict" class="form-control"></label>
<input type="hidden" name="predictDataTemp" id="predictData" value="something">
```

Comment: I already edit my code above, when I try to get the data still return null

Comment: did you put value in `<input type="hidden" name="predictDataTemp" value="something">` ?

Comment: Oh I know my problem, my input still null, how can I set value my predictDataTemp ? I use $('#predictData').append(dataTemp); but still null

Comment: Add id to input `id="predictData"` and use `$('#predictData').val(dataTemp);`